# Single global JMS Connector across flows or using multiple JMS configurations

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am a Mule newbie and have a best practice question:

My Mule application consists of multiple flows that are listening on multiple ActiveMQ message queues, which are following the states of jobs in the system and transactions that are being processed. 
I have set up a single JMS Connector Configuration, which is being shared by all the flows, both as an inbound endpoint and as an outbound endpoint.

Is this the correct set up, or do I need to use multiple JMS connectors?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single JMS connector may be shared amongst Mule Flows as you have described. Different connectors are used when you require different settings for different Flows.